# MongoDB + React - Obtain a document from db based on a query I am passing

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am trying to **access a document** from my MongoDB Atlas db that contains a specific key, **based on a query I am passing in the fetch**. I've followed the guides on the backend setup from MongoDB, it's all working, I'm connected to it, and now here's what I'm trying to do:

**Documents look like this:**

```js
{
  invitationCode: string;
  name: string;
  numberOfPeople: number;
  specialMentions: string;
  confirmed: boolean;
}
```

In the frontend, there's only one input at first, where the user should be entering his invitation Code. Once he clicks on the button, **a request should be made to the BE**, **sending the value he entered**. The BE should look through the documents and find the document that contains the invitationCode mathing with the input (The invitation codes are all unique). After the BE identified the document, **it should be sent back to the frontend**, so I can juggle with it here (display the name of the person, show the other 3 fields, etc.)

**Here's what I have so far:**

**in my record.js file (backend):**

```js
const express = require("express");
const recordRoutes = express.Router();
const dbo = require("../db/conn");
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

recordRoutes.route('/record/invitations').post(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = req.body.invitationNumber;
  console.log('MYQUERY:', myquery);
  
  db_connect
  .collection('records')
  .findOne({zzceva: myquery}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
   console.log('RESULT FROM BE', result);
   res.send(result);
  })
  console.log('QUERY:', myquery);
})
```

**and in the frontend I have this logic:**

```js
const onSubmit = useCallback(async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
 
   if (personEnteredCode) {
    const newPerson = { ...form };
 
    await fetch("http://localhost:5000/record/add", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
     body: JSON.stringify(newPerson),
    })
    .catch(error => {
      window.alert(error);
      return;
    });
  
    setForm({ invitationNumber: "", numberOfPeople: "", specialMentions: "" });
    navigate("/");
    console.log('newPerson:', newPerson);
   } else {
   // THIS IS WHAT DOES NOT WORK >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   // I AM TRYING TO SEND THE invCode back to the BE
    const invCode = form.invitationNumber;

   await fetch("http://localhost:5000/record/invitations", {
     method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(invCode),
           
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('THE RESPONSE IS:', response);
      setCurrentPerson(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      window.alert(error);
      return;
    })
    .finally(() => setPersonEnteredCode(true))
   }
   // When a post request is sent to the create url, we'll add a new record to the database.
  
  
 }, [form, navigate, personEnteredCode])
 
 
 return (
   <div className="confirm-form">
     
     <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="invitationCode">Cod invitație:</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="invitationCode"
           value={form.invitationNumber}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ invitationNumber: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>
       {!personEnteredCode && <input type={'submit'} value={'OK'}/>}
       {personEnteredCode && <div className="form-group">
         <label htmlFor="numberOfPeople">Număr persoane:</label>
         <input
           type="number"
           className="form-control"
           id="numberOfPeople"
           value={form.numberOfPeople}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ numberOfPeople: e.target.value })}
         />
       </div>}
       {personEnteredCode && <div className="form-group">
         <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
         <label htmlFor="specialMentions">Mențiuni speciale:</label>
         <input
           type="text"
           className="form-control"
           id="specialMentions"
           value={form.specialMentions}
           onChange={(e) => updateForm({ specialMentions: e.target.value })}
         />
         </div>
         
         
       </div>}
       {personEnteredCode &&<div className="form-group">
         <input
           type="submit"
           value="Confirmă"
           className="btn btn-primary"
         />
       </div>}
     </form>
    
   </div>
 );
}
```

After many different tries, now **the response I'm getting is 200** (not 404 not found or 500 like the first tries), but on the response object, I don't see the information I need, instead this is how a console.log looks like:

[image: The response I am currently getting from BE]

**HUGE thanks in advance for any kind of guidance or help you could provide. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're logging the [fetch response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) and not the data in the response body (so congrats! you're getting a response!).

The fetch response has a couple of different methods that you can use to read the data in the body.  Depending on the type of data your API is returning, you'll use the appropriate method (`.json`, `.text`, `.blob`, etc.).  These methods return a promise meaning they are asynchronous.  Here's how you might modify your code:

```js
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/record/invitations", {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(invCode)       
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      //now you've got the data to put in state
      setCurrentPerson(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      window.alert(error);
      return;
    })
   }
```

I can see that in your Express route, you're using `res.send(result)`.  You'll probably want to change that to: `res.json(result)`.  Both behave the same if you pass an object or array, but `res.json()` will explicitly convert your results to JSON.

Also, you didn't ask about it, but generally, you wouldn't use POST for this route.  In REST, this would be a GET route and you'd generally pass the data as a param or querystring to your API.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I figured this would have to be a GET request, since I'm actually requestion some sort of data - But how would a query be sent in a GET request? I see it doesn't allow a body... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ironessence glad this helped.  You are right that GET doesn't accept a body, that's why you'd use a querystring or path.  If you want some further advice on how to use a GET route, please make another question for it. (It helps others to find the answer in the future).